# Find in BindingList<T>

Tags: .net, winforms, bindinglist

How to find an object in BindingList that has a property equals to specific value. Below is my code.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; } 
    public string ProductName { get; set; }  
}

BindingList<Product> productList = new BindingList<Product>();
```

now consider that the productList has 100 products and i want to find the product object whose id is 10.

I can find it using

```
productList.ToList<Product>().Find(p =>p.ProductID == 1);
```

but i feel using ToList() is an unwanted overheard here.  Is there any direct way to do this, there is no 'Find' method in `BindingList<T>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) from LINQ instead of `Find`:

```
Product product = productList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == 1);
```

`product` will be null if there were no such products. If there's more than one match, an exception will be thrown.

You should really look into LINQ to Objects - it makes many operations on data *significantly* simpler.